# How to debug coffeescript on the server with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, phantomjs, spookyjs

I've got below code that is run with Coffeescript, NodeJS PhantomJS and SpookyJS

```
try 
  Spooky = require 'spooky'
  mysql = require 'mysql'
catch e
  console.log e
  Spooky = require 'node_modules/spooky/lib/spooky'


spooky = new Spooky(
  casper: ->
    logLevel: 'debug',
    verbose: true

  (err) ->
    if (err)
      e = new Error('Failed to initialize SpookyJS')
      e.details = err
      throw e

    spooky.on 'error', (e) ->
      console.error e

    spooky.on 'log', (log) ->
      if (log.space == 'remote')
        console.log log.message

    spooky.on 'console', (line) ->
      console.log line

    spooky.start 'http://www.website.com/'

    spooky.thenEvaluate ->
      console.log 'Hello, from', document.title;

    spooky.run;
)
```

In the console when I run with `coffee` command, it comes up with `[info] [phantom] Starting...` and hangs there.

Is there a way to debug this to find out what is going on or are there something wrong with the syntax itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `coffee --compile file.coffee` to attempt to compile a CoffeeScript file into JavaScript. If it compiles properly, then there are no CoffeeScript syntax errors, and you have the compiled JavaScript version that you can use to debug.